# mysql query with case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query that sorted by date difference.my sort currently work but i want to use case for condition like

if `priority<=10 THEN 10` will be add with current priority

my query currently return a default abnormal value of modified priority value

my query is

```
SELECT videoid,priority, 
      CASE WHEN priority<=10 THEN (priority+10)
           WHEN priority>10 and priority<=20 THEN (priority+9)
           WHEN priority<=30 THEN (priority+8) 
      END AS 'modified_priority', 
      DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),
      DATE(from_unixtime(submittime))) AS d 
FROM 
  `datatable` 
ORDER BY d
```

Comment: should not last part be priority>=30?

Comment: @user3660286: Define *'default abnormal value'*.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last case matches all. Try this

```
SELECT videoid,priority, 
      CASE WHEN priority <=10 THEN (priority+10)
           WHEN priority>10 and priority <=20 THEN (priority+9)
           WHEN priority>20 AND priority <=30 THEN (priority+8) 
      END AS `modified_priority`, 
      DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),
      DATE(from_unixtime(submittime))) AS d 
FROM 
  `datatable` 
ORDER BY d
```

Answer (score 3):

Case statements are processed in order, with the first matching condition being returned.  You can use this to your advantage and simplify the statement to:

```
SELECT videoid, priority, 
       (CASE WHEN priority <= 10 THEN (priority+10)
             WHEN priority <= 20 THEN (priority+9)
             WHEN priority <= 30 THEN (priority+8) 
        END) AS modified_priority, 
       DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(from_unixtime(submittime))) AS d 
FROM `datatable` 
ORDER BY d;
```

If you don't want to return `NULL` for priority values greater then 30, then you need an `ELSE` clause.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT videoid, priority, 
       (CASE WHEN priority <= 10 THEN (priority+10)
             WHEN priority <= 20 THEN (priority+9)
             WHEN priority <= 30 THEN (priority+8) 
             ELSE priority
        END) AS modified_priority, 
       DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(from_unixtime(submittime))) AS d 
FROM `datatable` 
ORDER BY d;
```

Also, I removed the single quotes from around `modified_priority`.  You should only use single quotes for string and date constants.